# Go to a specific line in terminal using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I had a Python code that print 33 line in terminal, so I want to jump back to line 11 and rewrite all text in that line, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a package like `curses` to take control of the terminal.  That's what apps like `vi` use to do their drawing.  That lets you draw strings at specific row and column position.

Answer (score 0):

This is why it's useful to have some familiarity with less.

You could use `11g` to jump to the beginning of the line or `11G` to jump to the end of the line.

Or from the command line, you could use `less +11 filename.py` or `less +11 -N filename.py` if you want to see the line numbers. You can also display a specific line of the file at a specific line of the terminal by using `less +11 -j 10 filename.py`.